# consistency and unbiasedness of ols estimator

Tags: econometrics, regression, statistics

[image]

Please explain why the OLS estimator is consistent and unbiased withregard to the equation below

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
C_{t} = \beta_{1} + \lambda   C_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

We can write $\varepsilon_t=\sum_{s=0}^\infty \rho^su_{t-s}$.

Thus, $Cov(\varepsilon_t, C_{t-1}) = Cov(\sum_{s=0}^\infty \rho^su_{t-s}, C_{t-1})$.

We are given that $E[u_t|C_{t-1},\varepsilon_{t-1}]=0$. Thus, $Cov(u_t, C_{t-1})=0$. To conclude there is consistency also requires that $Cov(u_{t-s},C_{t-1})=0$ for all $s>0$.

OLS is definitely biased. For unbiasedness, we need $E[u_t|C]=0$ where $C$ is a vector of $C_t$ at all time periods. This is impossible because $u_t$ is definitely correlated with $C_t$ (at the same time period).

Comment: and one last follow up:

Comment: Consider the following equation * \begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
C_{t} = \beta_{1} + \lambda   Y_{t} + \epsilon_{t}
\end{equation}
where,
\begin{equation} \label{eq:2}
E(\epsilon_{t}\mid Y_{t}) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
\epsilon_{t} = \rho\epsilon_{t-1} + u_{t}
\end{equation}
and the error component Ut, is iid with mean 0, constant variance, and\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
E(u_{t}\mid   Y_{t},\epsilon_{t-1}) = 0
\end{equation}

questions:
(i) Is the OLS estimator of the coefficients in (*) unbiased and consistent? Explain.

Comment: I would assume the ols estimator is  unbiased and consistent because Yt covers all time periods unlike c(t-1).

Comment: Also how would you conduct hypothesis tests in this case? Why?

Comment: It's still possible that $Cov(u_t, Y_s)\ne 0$ for some $t\ne s$, which would cause bias.
For inference, you can still do a standard t-test.